# jQuery mouseup not being fired when mousemove on image

Tags: jquery, mouseup

When you `mousedown` on an image, move the mouse (`mousemove`) a little bit and then release (`mouseup`), `mouseup` is not fired with jQuery.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kVFTZ/

Why is this? How can I make it work when moving on an image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found that `return false` solves the problem more appropriately.

As long as `e.preventDefault()` is called, text selection will be prevented too (probably some other actions), and it can not be undone.

I added `return false` to `mousedown` on images only

```
if(e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'img') {

    return false;

    // e.preventDefault() also does the job
    // but it prevents all default action
    // and can not be undone
}
```

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kVFTZ/4/

Answer (score 4):

Easy enough to fix. Add `event.preventDefault();` to your mousedown function.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/kVFTZ/3/)**

```
$(document).on('mousedown', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#info').text('Now move the mouse and then release');
    $('#log').text('mouse down fired');
}).on('mouseup', function() {
    $('#log').text('mouse up fired');
});
```

​

Comment: thanks, but `preventDefault` should go after other code that need to be executed (ele.text() in this case).